# Crystal Report in vb2008 shows the message "A string is required here"

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench, crystal-reports-2008

Days column is integer type in my Database

if {SubmitReport.Days} > 14 then crRed else crBlack

in the place of 14(integer) asking String is required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change the color of a textfield in a report, add a Formula for the color

[image]
[image]

is this what you exactly want to do??

Comment: I have already done this way but at the place of 14 which is integer, showing msg that "String is required"

Comment: I did exactly these steps already but error is same i.e "String is required"

Comment: what is exactly the datatype of your field Days? if it is a VARCHAR/string type,. try changing it into int,.